# Why does Volumes of CreateContainerOptions take a map[string]struct{}?

Tags: go, docker

I've been using the great [`go-dockerclient]`](https://github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient) created by [fsouza](https://github.com/fsouza) but I'm confused why `docker.CreateContainerOptions.Volumes` is a map of strings to structs?

[The docs don't explain](https://godoc.org/github.com/fsouza/go-dockerclient#Config) why this is but I'd imagine that you'd just need map[string] => string to map host volumes to container volumes? Or leave the value blank to say that the host volume will be mounted at the same path within the container.

I looked through a bunch [of open code on Github](https://github.com/search?p=3&q=go-dockerclient%20CreateContainerOptions%20Volumes%20language%3Ago&ref=searchresults&type=Code&utf8=%E2%9C%93) with people creating containers but I just saw a lot of examples of people mounting Volumes with just a string and an empty struct as the value.

I'm also new to Go so I might be missing something entirely obvious.

Comment: The other idiomatic variant of a set of strings is `map[string]bool` which occupies **slightly** more RAM but is a bit more natural.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The empty struct is the only type in go that occupies 0 (zero) Bytes of memory.

It is a common idiom to use an empty struct when you want to store *something* or signal *something*. But that *something* should be as small as possible.

In your case

```
map[string]struct{}
```

Is used to store just the map's keys with no values associated. 
This way you can quickly check if the map contains a key or not. (It's basically a set).

[Here](http://dave.cheney.net/2014/03/25/the-empty-struct) are a few examples of what you can do with empty structs.

Comment: Thank you for this answer. While technically this makes 100% sense, I think it's rather unfortunate that a data structure as common as a set is represented this way.

Comment: @dalanmiller I agree. But you gotta work with what you got, since go has no builtin set type.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know exactly how this package works, but `map[string]struct{}` is the Golang idiomatic way of representing a set. So my guess is that the key of the map must contain the full path of the volume...